# Chrome package Busted

Tags: apt, google-chrome, 15.10, reinstall

Running Ubuntu 15.10
and Chrome 64bit

I recently have tried to install an extension to chrome and the install process had an error and told me to restart the app.

When I closed chrome it did not open after that. i tried opening in terminal and from the applications folder.

i tried removing chrome from the software center so i can re-install it but it encountered a pipe error there too.

i tried removing chrome using the `sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable`.
but the same error poopped up there as well.

any help will be much appreciated!!

### EDIT :

another try with the apt-get was `sudo dpkg --force-all -r google-chrome-stable`

and also `sudo apt-get autoremove` 

and this time i got this error (same for both of them):

```
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--remove):
  unable to securely remove '/opt/google/chrome/xdg-mime': Not a directory
```

### EDIT : the screenshot of the opt application/gzip file

[weird opt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfmDs.png)

Comment: Just remove /opt/google/ with "rm" and re-install?!

Comment: i don't have a directory in /opt/google actually the opt is some wierd gzip that i tried to open with `gzip -d opt.g`  & `sudo gunzip opt.gz` and it told me that no such file exists. 
<br>
i put a screen in the main post

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've managed to solve this issue without needing to completely manually removing chrome.

I re-downloaded the .deb file from Google and used the force install and overwrite command from dpkg with the deb file and for now chrome works fine :=)

command: 
`sudo dpkg --force-all -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

this completely ignored all errors and overwrites the current package already installed.

gr8 relief.